# How to call resizeEvent, closeEvent, cancel on QGIS Plugin?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-plugins

Hi I am building a plugin in QGIS using the [Plugin Builder](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/pluginbuilder/). I want to add an action when I resize the dialog widget, close the plugin UI (press the close button 'X' on upper right in Windows), and when I press cancel on the generic dialog box. Basically I want to reset some settings.

Where would I place e.g. `some_reset_function()` in this [application](https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/3/building_a_python_plugin.html) for example. Full code is found below the link.

Comment: This is more a PyQt question than a GIS one. Have you searched in SO? https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=pyqt+close+event Look for instance: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54540934/pyqt-intercept-close-event-without-inheritance

Comment: Yes. I am not just sure how to inherit them on the main code generated from the Plugin Builder. Thanks!